# Proper way to transform image in google slides api with dynamic height

Tags: google-slides-api

I'm trying to translate an image of dynamic height and fixed width to an absolute position on a google slide, maintaining a 1:1 aspect ratio.

For example, my original images could be (in pixels):
200x150
or
200x220

I want to move it so they are both offset by x: 100, y:200, keep the original aspect ratio, and make sure the width is always fixed to the same size in PX but height is variable.

I am struggling to calculate the correct transform to make the correct translation.

```
{
'createImage': {
  objectId,
  url,
  elementProperties: {
    pageObjectId,

    size: {
      width: {
        magnitude: (7/9)*originalWidthPx, //pixel to PT conversion
        unit: 'PT',
      },
      height: {
        magnitude: (7/9)*originalHeightPx, //pixel to PT conversion
        unit: 'PT',
      },
    },
    transform: {
      scaleX: 1, // I believe i'll need to scale the image based on Height, keeping the original aspect ratio 
      scaleY: 1,
      translateX: 100, // i dont believe this needs to be dynamic based on w/h
      translateY: 200,
      unit: 'PT',
    },
  }, 
},
```

}

Comment: Your sample request seems right to me, and doing my own CreateImage request appears to behave correctly as well. Mind providing a bit more detail on what you expect to happen, and what you observe happening with this snippet?

Comment: Hi Maurice, sorry for the delay.

Here is a gist with exact reproduce steps and screenshots of the incorrect height offset i am experiencing. I must not be translating correctly to account for the difference in heights. 

https://gist.github.com/aaronryden/79746162f55ab948808f30630d28dbd1

Comment: In that gist, it looks like the heights aren't converted to pts properly -- they are specified as 150 and 200. If you fix that, the images become top aligned properly.